# (AS3) Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, so I have this class that basically acts as a manager of an enemy. For some reason, whenever I try to make a bullet instance within the class and use addChild(), I get Error #1009. Here's the code:

```
var bullet:EnemyBullet = new EnemyBullet();

stage.addChild(bullet);   //Error comes up here

bullet.x = enemy.x;
bullet.y = enemy.y;

bManager.bulletVector.push(bullet);
```

I've been using this method for two other classes without issue, so I'm stuck. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing because the class does not know where the stage is

the way to handle that would be to use anAddedToStage event handler, and put the `stage.addChild` code within

Comment: Also, if the "manager class" don't extends any class from AS, e.g. Moviclip/Sprite, there is no reference to stage ...

Comment: @Rizzla I made it so that it extends as a Movieclip, so it should have a reference to the stage.

Comment: Okay, so I did a trace() test to see if the bullets actually get initialized. Apparently they don't. I'm really confused now.